# How to redirect from HTTP port 8080 to HTTPS 8443?

Tags: apache, ssl, https, tomcat7

I do have a java application running on Tomcat 7 at port 8080. I want to enable SSL and have access to it via HTTPS. What I've done so far:

I've followed by this tut http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-ssl.

SSL didnt work as my tomcat by default was configured using some `apr`. I commented the following line of server conf file

`Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"`

and now it runs fine, and I can access my app as usual at port 8080 without any SSL. When i type port 8443, it gives to me some 7kb file to download and that's it.

I was thinking that, when I enable the SSL it should automatically redirect from port 8080 to 8443 if SSL enabled. But it doesn' do it.

Could u please point me to my mistake.

Comment: If you want HTTP:8080 -> HTTPS:8443 then add `<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" />` and `<Connector port="8443" ... SSLEnabled="true" .../>` in your **server.xml**. If you want to redirect HTTP:8443 -> HTTPS:8443, see a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21175842/http-request-port-8443 (without answers at this moment).